# NMap show only IP addresses that are down

Tags: linux, nmap

An excellent command shows only those IP addresses that are responding

```
nmap -n -sn 192.168.1.0/24 -oG - | awk '/Up$/{print $2}'
```

Looking through all these can be a pain to find a few that are not responding (if looking to allocate a free IP). Is there a one-liner that shows only those addresses that are not responding?

Comment: Not with nmap, but here's a one-liner: `fping -q -u -g 192.168.1.0/24`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`nmap`](https://nmap.org/book/man-output.html) has a verbose option `-v`:

> Verbosity and debugging options
>
> `-v` (Increase verbosity level), `-vlevel` (Set verbosity level)
>
> Increases the verbosity level, causing Nmap to print more information
> about the scan in progress.

It will display all hosts that were scanned rather than only those that answer and show those that didn't answer in `Down` state. So just filter this with `Down` in results instead of `Up`:

```
    nmap -n -sn -v 192.168.1.0/24 -oG - | awk '/Down$/{print $2}'
```

One should remove first and last element of the result since these are the network (here 192.168.1.0) and broadcast addresses (192.168.1.255) usually not available for systems. As order is not guaranteed a version sort is also needed:

```
    nmap -n -sn -v 192.168.1.0/24 -oG - | grep '^Host:' | sort -k 2 -V | tail -n +2 | head -n -1 | awk '/Down$/{print $2}'
```

Note: `nmap` has an XML output (using `-oX -`) which should probably be more reliable to use in scripts along tools like `xmlstarlet` or `xmllint`. Alas it's not as easily usable as JSON with the `jq` tool, so I didn't attempt to use this format.

Comment: Found there are `jq` wrappers that take XML input. For example with [`yq`](https://pypi.org/project/yq/)'s `xq` command the first line in my answer could be written: `nmap -n -v -sn 192.168.1.0/24 -oX - | xq -r '.nmaprun.host[] | if (.status."@state" == "down") then .address."@addr" else empty end'`

Answer (score 0):

Why using nmap for this ?
I would have done it that way:

```
for ((i=0;i<255;i++)); do ping -W 1 -c 1 192.168.1.${i} >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo "192.168.1.${i} is available" ; done
```

Note that:

- `-W 1` is to set timeout to 1 second
- `-c 1` is to send only one ICMP Echo Request before exiting.

Comment: Thanks, Im using nmap because I am using it for other things and you can use the CIDR notation